# How do I go about fixing this IF AND nested formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am new to spreadsheets so I'm not sure if I'm taking the wrong approach to this but basically I want to show a 'rank' when someone has the required number to get that. For example, if someone has between 20-39 points they will be ranked Footman.

Here is the current formula:

```
IF(AND(L15>20,L15<60,L15=20, "Footman", IF(AND(L15>60,L15=60,L15<100,"Man at arms","Conscript"))))
```

The formula is returning N/A* saying that it expected two-three arguments but got one. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check your closing parentheses for the `AND`s. Also, why the `=` checks? (`L15=20` and `L15=60`)? Maybe you meant `L15>=20`, instead of including both `L15>20` and `L15=20` in your logic?

Comment: That was me trying to fix the problem with the L15=20 and L=60. It might be a problem with the closing parenthesis but trying to change the number of closing parenthesis returned the same N/A. (I changed the closing parenthesis from 3, 4, 5 etc.)

Comment: `=IF(AND(L15>=20,L15<60),"Footman",IF(AND(L15>=60,L15<100),"Man at arms", "Conscript"))`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IF((L15>=20)*(L15<60),  "Footman",
 IF((L15>=60)*(L15<100), "Man at arms", "Conscript"))
```

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((L15:L>=20)*(L15:L<60),  "Footman",
 IF((L15:L>=60)*(L15:L<100), "Man at arms", "Conscript")))
```

but you can also use match, ifs, vlookup... see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been answered, but is this a slightly simpler formula?

=IFS( L15>=60, "Man at Arms", L15>=20, "Footman", L15<20, "Conscript" )

or to fill the column down,

=ARRAYFORMULA( IFS( L15:L >= 60, "Man at Arms", L15:L >= 20, "Footman", L15 < 20, "Conscript"))